# how to convert mysql_fetch_array to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I have a problem,im trying to convert php standard to CodeIgniter, But I dont know how to convert ths code, please help, and thanks a lot.

```
    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("ardefa");
    $borneo=mysql_query("select* from borneo");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($borneo))
    {
       ?>
         <a href="#"><li><img src="
         <?php 
         $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? ($_GET['page']):"";

         if ($page =='borneo')
         {
            echo $row["img"];
         }
         ?>">
         </li></a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you'll need to learn the actual framework itself first, and its too broad it put it in an answer, from using controllers, models, and view. why not try the framework first, start building it, im sure there are a lot of resources lying out there, it isn't something new anyways

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
      $data = $this->db->get('borneo')->result_array(); // All row
    
    $this->db->select('*');
      $data = $this->db->get('borneo')->result_array(); // single row

Comment: thanks for your comment, i know that structure, about controllers, models, and view, how about wihile and mysql_fetch_array in CI?

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

You don’t need to use `db_select` if you have single database, if multiple database you only need to use a different database on the same connection. You can switch to a different database when you need to using this `$this->db->db_select('ardefa');`

*You can do like this :*

```
//$this->db->db_select('ardefa');
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('borneo');
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
   /*for multiple array*/

   $result = $query->result_array();
   /*print here to see the result
   print_r($result);
   */
}
```

*Use $result like this :*

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo $row;
}
```

Or can also do it like this :

```
//$this->db->db_select('ardefa');
$query = $this->db->get('borneo');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
   /*for multiple array*/

   $result = $query->result_array();
   /*for single array
   $row = $query->row_array();
   */
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will help you

**MODEL**

```
public function your_function(){
    return $this->db->get('borneo')->reslut_array();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

$this->load->model('model-name');
$data = $this->model-name->model_function();
foreach($data as $row){
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == "borneo"){ ?>
        <a href="#"><li><img src="<?php echo $row['img']?>" /></li></a>
<?php } } ?>
```